# What is the acronym for investments that only billionaires can make?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, international-finance

Some time ago I read that when a product had high profitability possibilities, investments were opened exclusively to billionaires and any millionaire, no matter how much they met the required amount, could have access to that investment.

What is this type of investment called?

Comment: I don't think we can guess which acronym you are trying to find without a much more exact description. There are many investments that most folks simply cannot afford to get involved with --venture capital is one such -- and you haven't given us enough information to guess which one you are thinking of or even if there _is_ something specific that you're thinking of.

Comment: @keshlam That's all I remember, I know that once someone here asked for help on how he could invest in this type of investments exclusive for the elite, that no matter how much he insisted they wouldn't let him in, I think they were always for revolutionary products in the market whose creators opened the investments only for billionaires.

Comment: Sounds more like someone's paranoid fantasy than anything real...

Comment: @keshlam No, it was all official terminology, I saw it on google, on wikipedia, I saw it on quora and reddit, the thing is I don't remember what acronyms they used.

Comment: Post links to those instances, then. I don't think we can help you based on what you've given us.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is venture capital, which is certainly not restricted to billionaires. If that isn't it, I suggest we close this as unguessable without (apparently unavailable) additional information. Frankly, it sounds like conspiracy theory rather than fact

Answer (score 2):

Two terms I keep finding:

- [Accredited investor](https://www.sec.gov/education/capitalraising/building-blocks/accredited-investor) which is defined by the SEC. Though is doesn't have an acronym.
- High-net-worth individual (HNWI), is less well defined though it does have an acronym.

Comment: Neither of these examples refer to situations where an investment opportunity is closed to people who are not super wealthy because it is supposed to be highly profitable. On the contrary, accredited investors exists to protect investors who might not have the cash reserves to weather significant losses.

Comment: Qualified eligible participants (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qep.asp) are another - similar to accredited investors but with some differences.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for :(

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is scam. Accredited investors is the closest thing I've heard to what you are talking about. It isn't limited to billionaires per se, but is limited to people with either (a) substantial wealth; or (b) extensive investing knowledge. This is because these are very high risk investments.